# Using Facepunch Steamworks Wrapper P2P connection "NoRightsToApp" error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steamworks-api

I am currently trying to use the p2p library of facepunch's steamworks library but It gives me this error:
[image]

This is my code for the P2P connection:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Steamworks;

public class FacePunchSteamPeerToPeer : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        SteamNetworking.OnP2PSessionRequest = (steamid) =>
        {
            print("Accepting User");
            // If we want to let this steamid talk to us
            SteamNetworking.AcceptP2PSessionWithUser(steamid);
        };
        SteamNetworking.OnP2PConnectionFailed = (SteamId, P2PSessionError) =>
        {
            print(P2PSessionError);
        };
    }

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
    {
        byte[] mydata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello");
        SteamId TargetSteamId = (SteamId)76561198017227431;
        var sent = SteamNetworking.SendP2PPacket(TargetSteamId, mydata);
    }

    while (SteamNetworking.IsP2PPacketAvailable())
    {
        var packet = SteamNetworking.ReadP2PPacket();
        if (packet.HasValue)
        {
            HandleMessageFrom(packet.Value.SteamId, packet.Value.Data);
        }
    }
}

void HandleMessageFrom(SteamId steamid, byte[] data)
{
    print("Data Received");
}

}
```

I dont know what Im doing wrong or what that error means

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I was using the wrong app id in one of the computers I was using